# Validate in handle request or skip to validator

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have a form that has numerous pages and completes the validation at the very end once all are completed.  I have a text box that I need validated to ensure the user has not entered too much to save in a database field in most pages.  Since the controller is set up to only validate at the very end it goes to a handle request function and only calls the onbindvalidate function at the very last page.  I want this validated every time the user enters too much into the box and I was wondering if there was a way to skip the handle request when this happens and go to the onbindvalidate function.  I can't remove the handle request because it is dealing with document upload.

Right now my code catches the exception if a user enters in too much and it cant be saved to the DB and redirects back to the page and this done in the handle request.  Is there a way I can pass it back with the error object through the handle request or skip the handle request any time this exception happens.  The handle request returns a ModelAndView.  Either way as long as I redirect back with errors.

Comment: Use javascript validation :)

Answer (score 0):

To handle it you can simply use javascript validation.

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
```

Or simple ajax call. To validate your content and stay on the same page.

example

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

Comment: Would I just use the validateForm() on the button submit ?

Comment: Yes you can do it on submit